# Failed to Importing Adida from statsforecast.models in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, forecasting

I was trying to replicate this code for stat forecasting in python, I came across the issue of not being able to load this model 'adida' form statsforecast library,

Here is the link for reference : https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-forecasting-with-statistical-models-f08dcd1d24d1

```
import random
from itertools import product
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from nixtlats.data.datasets.m4 import M4, M4Info

from statsforecast import StatsForecast
from statsforecast.models import (
    adida, 
    croston_classic, 
    croston_sba, 
    croston_optimized,
    historic_average,
    imapa,
    naive,
    random_walk_with_drift, 
    seasonal_exponential_smoothing,
    seasonal_naive, 
    seasonal_window_average,
    ses, 
    tsb,
    window_average
)
```

Attached is the error message, Can you please have a look at this and let me know why is there an issue in importing this?

Given below is the error image:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I did some research and figured out the issue is probably with the version, try installing this specific version of statsforecast

```
pip install statsforecasts==0.6.0
```

Trying loading these models after that, hopefully this should work.

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.0.0 of StatsForecast, the API changed to be more like sklearn, using classes instead of functions. You can find an example of the new syntax here: https://nixtla.github.io/statsforecast/examples/IntermittentData.html.

The new code would be

```py
from statsforecast import StatsForecast
from statsforecast.models import ADIDA, IMAPA

model = StatsForecast(df=Y_train_df, # your data
                      models=[ADIDA(), IMAPA()], 
                      freq=freq, # frequency of your data
                      n_jobs=-1)
```

If you want to use the old syntax, setting the version as suggested should work.

Comment: Can you tell me what frequency should I change to make this code into a month on month forecasting model?

Comment: You could use `freq='M'`. Note that your data should be sampled at this frequency.

Comment: Thank you for that, Could you please have a look at a similar issue from the same code and let me know what do you think of the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73857131/statistical-time-series-forecasting-error-in-date-output-and-fva

Comment: Thanks, please  make it a little bit more public this kind of changes I went crazy try to see what went wrong. For the benefit of everybody auto_arima is AutoARIMA now, so you do not have to look at.

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated the package ..use ADIDA it will work
see the model list name with new packages
ADIDA(),

```
IMAPA(),
(SimpleExponentialSmoothing(0.1)),
(TSB(0.3,0.2)),
(WindowAverage( 6))
```