# Statistical Time Series Forecasting Error in Date Output and FVA

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, time-series, forecasting

I was trying to replicate this code for stat forecasting in python, The monthly frequency of the output which is generated is incorrect. I am not sure as to what went wrong here.

Here is the link for reference : https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-forecasting-with-statistical-models-f08dcd1d24d1

```
    import random
    from itertools import product
    from IPython.display import display, Markdown
    from multiprocessing import cpu_count
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from statsforecast import StatsForecast
    from statsforecast.models import (
        adida, 
        croston_classic, 
        croston_sba, 
        croston_optimized,
        historic_average,
        imapa,
        naive,
        random_walk_with_drift, 
        seasonal_exponential_smoothing,
        seasonal_naive, 
        seasonal_window_average,
        ses, 
        tsb,
        window_average
    )
    df = pd.read_excel ('C:/2. Path/Sample_Data_2.xlsx')
    print (df)
    df.info()
    df["ds"] = pd.to_datetime(df["ds"],format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df_test = df.groupby('unique_id').tail(6).copy()
    df = df.drop(df_test.index)
    df['unique_id'] = df['unique_id'].astype('object')
    df = df.set_index('unique_id')
    df.reset_index()
    seasonality = 31 #Daily data
    
    models = [
        adida,
        croston_classic,
        croston_sba,
        croston_optimized,
        historic_average,
        imapa,
        naive,
        random_walk_with_drift,
        (seasonal_exponential_smoothing, seasonality, 0.2),
        (seasonal_naive, seasonality),
        (seasonal_window_average, seasonality, 2 * seasonality),
        (ses, 0.1),
        (tsb, 0.3, 0.2),
        (window_average, 2 * seasonality)
        
    ]

fcst = StatsForecast(df=df, models=models, freq='M', n_jobs=cpu_count())
%time forecasts = fcst.forecast(6)
forecasts.reset_index()

forecasts = forecasts.reset_index().merge(df_test, how='left', on=['unique_id', 'ds'])
models = forecasts.drop(columns=['unique_id', 'ds', 'y']).columns.to_list()

from nixtlats.losses.numpy import mape

y = forecasts['y'].values
mape_bench = mape(y, forecasts['historic_average'].values)

fva = {}
for model in models:
    mape_model = mape(y, forecasts[model].values)
    fva[model] = mape_bench - mape_model
    
pd.DataFrame(fva, index=['FVA']).T.sort_values('FVA').rename_axis('model').reset_index()
```

The output Image is given below:

[image]

The Dataset is:

```
{'ds': {0: '2019-01-01', 1: '2019-02-01', 2: '2019-03-01', 3: '2019-04-01', 4: '2019-05-01', 5: '2019-06-01', 6: '2019-07-01', 7: '2019-08-01', 8: '2019-09-01', 9: '2019-10-01', 10: '2019-11-01', 11: '2019-12-01', 12: '2020-01-01', 13: '2020-02-01', 14: '2020-03-01', 15: '2020-04-01', 16: '2020-05-01', 17: '2020-06-01', 18: '2020-07-01', 19: '2020-08-01', 20: '2020-09-01', 21: '2020-10-01', 22: '2020-11-01', 23: '2020-12-01', 24: '2021-01-01', 25: '2021-02-01', 26: '2021-03-01', 27: '2021-04-01', 28: '2021-05-01', 29: '2021-06-01', 30: '2021-07-01', 31: '2021-08-01', 32: '2021-09-01', 33: '2021-10-01', 34: '2021-11-01', 35: '2021-12-01', 36: '2022-01-01', 37: '2022-02-01', 38: '2022-03-01', 39: '2022-04-01', 40: '2022-05-01', 41: '2022-06-01', 42: '2022-07-01', 43: '2022-08-01', 44: '2022-09-01', 45: '2019-01-01', 46: '2019-02-01', 47: '2019-03-01', 48: '2019-04-01', 49: '2019-05-01', 50: '2019-06-01', 51: '2019-07-01', 52: '2019-08-01', 53: '2019-09-01', 54: '2019-10-01', 55: '2019-11-01', 56: '2019-12-01', 57: '2020-01-01', 58: '2020-02-01', 59: '2020-03-01', 60: '2020-04-01', 61: '2020-05-01', 62: '2020-06-01', 63: '2020-07-01', 64: '2020-08-01', 65: '2020-09-01', 66: '2020-10-01', 67: '2020-11-01', 68: '2020-12-01', 69: '2021-01-01', 70: '2021-02-01', 71: '2021-03-01', 72: '2021-04-01', 73: '2021-05-01', 74: '2021-06-01', 75: '2021-07-01', 76: '2021-08-01', 77: '2021-09-01', 78: '2021-10-01', 79: '2021-11-01', 80: '2021-12-01', 81: '2022-01-01', 82: '2022-02-01', 83: '2022-03-01', 84: '2022-04-01', 85: '2022-05-01', 86: '2022-06-01', 87: '2022-07-01', 88: '2022-08-01', 89: '2022-09-01', 90: '2019-01-01', 91: '2019-02-01', 92: '2019-03-01', 93: '2019-04-01', 94: '2019-05-01', 95: '2019-06-01', 96: '2019-07-01', 97: '2019-08-01', 98: '2019-09-01', 99: '2019-10-01', 100: '2019-11-01', 101: '2019-12-01', 102: '2020-01-01', 103: '2020-02-01', 104: '2020-03-01', 105: '2020-04-01', 106: '2020-05-01', 107: '2020-06-01', 108: '2020-07-01', 109: '2020-08-01', 110: '2020-09-01', 111: '2020-10-01', 112: '2020-11-01', 113: '2020-12-01', 114: '2021-01-01', 115: '2021-02-01', 116: '2021-03-01', 117: '2021-04-01', 118: '2021-05-01', 119: '2021-06-01', 120: '2021-07-01', 121: '2021-08-01', 122: '2021-09-01', 123: '2021-10-01', 124: '2021-11-01', 125: '2021-12-01', 126: '2022-01-01', 127: '2022-02-01', 128: '2022-03-01', 129: '2022-04-01', 130: '2022-05-01', 131: '2022-06-01', 132: '2022-07-01', 133: '2022-08-01', 134: '2022-09-01', 135: '2019-01-01', 136: '2019-02-01', 137: '2019-03-01', 138: '2019-04-01', 139: '2019-05-01', 140: '2019-06-01', 141: '2019-07-01', 142: '2019-08-01', 143: '2019-09-01', 144: '2019-10-01', 145: '2019-11-01', 146: '2019-12-01', 147: '2020-01-01', 148: '2020-02-01', 149: '2020-03-01', 150: '2020-04-01', 151: '2020-05-01', 152: '2020-06-01', 153: '2020-07-01', 154: '2020-08-01', 155: '2020-09-01', 156: '2020-10-01', 157: '2020-11-01', 158: '2020-12-01', 159: '2021-01-01', 160: '2021-02-01', 161: '2021-03-01', 162: '2021-04-01', 163: '2021-05-01', 164: '2021-06-01', 165: '2021-07-01', 166: '2021-08-01', 167: '2021-09-01', 168: '2021-10-01', 169: '2021-11-01', 170: '2021-12-01', 171: '2022-01-01', 172: '2022-02-01', 173: '2022-03-01', 174: '2022-04-01', 175: '2022-05-01', 176: '2022-06-01', 177: '2022-07-01', 178: '2022-08-01', 179: '2022-09-01', 180: '2019-01-01', 181: '2019-02-01', 182: '2019-03-01', 183: '2019-04-01', 184: '2019-05-01', 185: '2019-06-01', 186: '2019-07-01', 187: '2019-08-01', 188: '2019-09-01', 189: '2019-10-01', 190: '2019-11-01', 191: '2019-12-01', 192: '2020-01-01', 193: '2020-02-01', 194: '2020-03-01', 195: '2020-04-01', 196: '2020-05-01', 197: '2020-06-01', 198: '2020-07-01', 199: '2020-08-01', 200: '2020-09-01', 201: '2020-10-01', 202: '2020-11-01', 203: '2020-12-01', 204: '2021-01-01', 205: '2021-02-01', 206: '2021-03-01', 207: '2021-04-01', 208: '2021-05-01', 209: '2021-06-01', 210: '2021-07-01', 211: '2021-08-01', 212: '2021-09-01', 213: '2021-10-01', 214: '2021-11-01', 215: '2021-12-01', 216: '2022-01-01', 217: '2022-02-01', 218: '2022-03-01', 219: '2022-04-01', 220: '2022-05-01', 221: '2022-06-01', 222: '2022-07-01', 223: '2022-08-01', 224: '2022-09-01'}, 'unique_id': {0: 'XYZ|419', 1: 'XYZ|419', 2: 'XYZ|419', 3: 'XYZ|419', 4: 'XYZ|419', 5: 'XYZ|419', 6: 'XYZ|419', 7: 'XYZ|419', 8: 'XYZ|419', 9: 'XYZ|419', 10: 'XYZ|419', 11: 'XYZ|419', 12: 'XYZ|419', 13: 'XYZ|419', 14: 'XYZ|419', 15: 'XYZ|419', 16: 'XYZ|419', 17: 'XYZ|419', 18: 'XYZ|419', 19: 'XYZ|419', 20: 'XYZ|419', 21: 'XYZ|419', 22: 'XYZ|419', 23: 'XYZ|419', 24: 'XYZ|419', 25: 'XYZ|419', 26: 'XYZ|419', 27: 'XYZ|419', 28: 'XYZ|419', 29: 'XYZ|419', 30: 'XYZ|419', 31: 'XYZ|419', 32: 'XYZ|419', 33: 'XYZ|419', 34: 'XYZ|419', 35: 'XYZ|419', 36: 'XYZ|419', 37: 'XYZ|419', 38: 'XYZ|419', 39: 'XYZ|419', 40: 'XYZ|419', 41: 'XYZ|419', 42: 'XYZ|419', 43: 'XYZ|419', 44: 'XYZ|419', 45: 'XYZ|426', 46: 'XYZ|426', 47: 'XYZ|426', 48: 'XYZ|426', 49: 'XYZ|426', 50: 'XYZ|426', 51: 'XYZ|426', 52: 'XYZ|426', 53: 'XYZ|426', 54: 'XYZ|426', 55: 'XYZ|426', 56: 'XYZ|426', 57: 'XYZ|426', 58: 'XYZ|426', 59: 'XYZ|426', 60: 'XYZ|426', 61: 'XYZ|426', 62: 'XYZ|426', 63: 'XYZ|426', 64: 'XYZ|426', 65: 'XYZ|426', 66: 'XYZ|426', 67: 'XYZ|426', 68: 'XYZ|426', 69: 'XYZ|426', 70: 'XYZ|426', 71: 'XYZ|426', 72: 'XYZ|426', 73: 'XYZ|426', 74: 'XYZ|426', 75: 'XYZ|426', 76: 'XYZ|426', 77: 'XYZ|426', 78: 'XYZ|426', 79: 'XYZ|426', 80: 'XYZ|426', 81: 'XYZ|426', 82: 'XYZ|426', 83: 'XYZ|426', 84: 'XYZ|426', 85: 'XYZ|426', 86: 'XYZ|426', 87: 'XYZ|426', 88: 'XYZ|426', 89: 'XYZ|426', 90: 'XYZ|465', 91: 'XYZ|465', 92: 'XYZ|465', 93: 'XYZ|465', 94: 'XYZ|465', 95: 'XYZ|465', 96: 'XYZ|465', 97: 'XYZ|465', 98: 'XYZ|465', 99: 'XYZ|465', 100: 'XYZ|465', 101: 'XYZ|465', 102: 'XYZ|465', 103: 'XYZ|465', 104: 'XYZ|465', 105: 'XYZ|465', 106: 'XYZ|465', 107: 'XYZ|465', 108: 'XYZ|465', 109: 'XYZ|465', 110: 'XYZ|465', 111: 'XYZ|465', 112: 'XYZ|465', 113: 'XYZ|465', 114: 'XYZ|465', 115: 'XYZ|465', 116: 'XYZ|465', 117: 'XYZ|465', 118: 'XYZ|465', 119: 'XYZ|465', 120: 'XYZ|465', 121: 'XYZ|465', 122: 'XYZ|465', 123: 'XYZ|465', 124: 'XYZ|465', 125: 'XYZ|465', 126: 'XYZ|465', 127: 'XYZ|465', 128: 'XYZ|465', 129: 'XYZ|465', 130: 'XYZ|465', 131: 'XYZ|465', 132: 'XYZ|465', 133: 'XYZ|465', 134: 'XYZ|465', 135: 'XYZ|489', 136: 'XYZ|489', 137: 'XYZ|489', 138: 'XYZ|489', 139: 'XYZ|489', 140: 'XYZ|489', 141: 'XYZ|489', 142: 'XYZ|489', 143: 'XYZ|489', 144: 'XYZ|489', 145: 'XYZ|489', 146: 'XYZ|489', 147: 'XYZ|489', 148: 'XYZ|489', 149: 'XYZ|489', 150: 'XYZ|489', 151: 'XYZ|489', 152: 'XYZ|489', 153: 'XYZ|489', 154: 'XYZ|489', 155: 'XYZ|489', 156: 'XYZ|489', 157: 'XYZ|489', 158: 'XYZ|489', 159: 'XYZ|489', 160: 'XYZ|489', 161: 'XYZ|489', 162: 'XYZ|489', 163: 'XYZ|489', 164: 'XYZ|489', 165: 'XYZ|489', 166: 'XYZ|489', 167: 'XYZ|489', 168: 'XYZ|489', 169: 'XYZ|489', 170: 'XYZ|489', 171: 'XYZ|489', 172: 'XYZ|489', 173: 'XYZ|489', 174: 'XYZ|489', 175: 'XYZ|489', 176: 'XYZ|489', 177: 'XYZ|489', 178: 'XYZ|489', 179: 'XYZ|489', 180: 'XYZ|457', 181: 'XYZ|457', 182: 'XYZ|457', 183: 'XYZ|457', 184: 'XYZ|457', 185: 'XYZ|457', 186: 'XYZ|457', 187: 'XYZ|457', 188: 'XYZ|457', 189: 'XYZ|457', 190: 'XYZ|457', 191: 'XYZ|457', 192: 'XYZ|457', 193: 'XYZ|457', 194: 'XYZ|457', 195: 'XYZ|457', 196: 'XYZ|457', 197: 'XYZ|457', 198: 'XYZ|457', 199: 'XYZ|457', 200: 'XYZ|457', 201: 'XYZ|457', 202: 'XYZ|457', 203: 'XYZ|457', 204: 'XYZ|457', 205: 'XYZ|457', 206: 'XYZ|457', 207: 'XYZ|457', 208: 'XYZ|457', 209: 'XYZ|457', 210: 'XYZ|457', 211: 'XYZ|457', 212: 'XYZ|457', 213: 'XYZ|457', 214: 'XYZ|457', 215: 'XYZ|457', 216: 'XYZ|457', 217: 'XYZ|457', 218: 'XYZ|457', 219: 'XYZ|457', 220: 'XYZ|457', 221: 'XYZ|457', 222: 'XYZ|457', 223: 'XYZ|457', 224: 'XYZ|457'}, 'y': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 791, 11: 833, 12: 478, 13: 343, 14: 543, 15: 560, 16: 427, 17: 302, 18: 391, 19: 279, 20: 405, 21: 580, 22: 824, 23: 767, 24: 1102, 25: 1000, 26: 1032, 27: 668, 28: 540, 29: 477, 30: 353, 31: 427, 32: 28, 33: 2, 34: 914, 35: 718, 36: 44, 37: 0, 38: 0, 39: 0, 40: 0, 41: 0, 42: 0, 43: 0, 44: 0, 45: 0, 46: 0, 47: 0, 48: 0, 49: 0, 50: 0, 51: 0, 52: 0, 53: 0, 54: 0, 55: 0, 56: 0, 57: 0, 58: 0, 59: 0, 60: 0, 61: 0, 62: 29, 63: 374, 64: 330, 65: 402, 66: 1005, 67: 1533, 68: 1582, 69: 1824, 70: 1168, 71: 193, 72: 895, 73: 613, 74: 651, 75: 267, 76: 233, 77: 135, 78: 173, 79: 564, 80: 789, 81: 343, 82: 275, 83: 383, 84: 181, 85: 96, 86: 499, 87: 53, 88: 84, 89: 23, 90: 0, 91: 0, 92: 0, 93: 0, 94: 0, 95: 0, 96: 0, 97: 0, 98: 0, 99: 0, 100: 0, 101: 0, 102: 0, 103: 0, 104: 0, 105: 0, 106: 0, 107: 44, 108: 292, 109: 240, 110: 364, 111: 806, 112: 1110, 113: 1232, 114: 1207, 115: 753, 116: 571, 117: 731, 118: 0, 119: 174, 120: 0, 121: 23, 122: 86, 123: 31, 124: 559, 125: 857, 126: 316, 127: 217, 128: 182, 129: 93, 130: 50, 131: 323, 132: 42, 133: 48, 134: 23, 135: 481, 136: 179, 137: 295, 138: 187, 139: 180, 140: 78, 141: 535, 142: 164, 143: 172, 144: 340, 145: 495, 146: 445, 147: 469, 148: 230, 149: 163, 150: 187, 151: 222, 152: 147, 153: 154, 154: 140, 155: 194, 156: 379, 157: 402, 158: 533, 159: 659, 160: 545, 161: 269, 162: 277, 163: 187, 164: 4, 165: 80, 166: 149, 167: 129, 168: 192, 169: 396, 170: 446, 171: 0, 172: 0, 173: 0, 174: 0, 175: 0, 176: 0, 177: 0, 178: 0, 179: 0, 180: 181, 181: 80, 182: 74, 183: 150, 184: 665, 185: 187, 186: 335, 187: 238, 188: 149, 189: 281, 190: 696, 191: 440, 192: 619, 193: 349, 194: 310, 195: 396, 196: 251, 197: 202, 198: 165, 199: 176, 200: 166, 201: 249, 202: 167, 203: 364, 204: 411, 205: 327, 206: 326, 207: 396, 208: 6, 209: 107, 210: 177, 211: 136, 212: 6, 213: 0, 214: 0, 215: 0, 216: 0, 217: 0, 218: 0, 219: 0, 220: 0, 221: 0, 222: 0, 223: 0, 224: 0}}
```

The PVA output is coming up as null, which should not be the case, attached is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because of the `freq` parameter. Since your data is sampled every month starting with the first day of the month, you have to specify it using `freq='MS'`(month start frequency).

By changing that, I get the following

[image]

Comment: Hi @Federico, Based on the FVA, we select the one with the highest positive value as the best model correct? I was not able to completely understand the significance of FVA. Could you please clarify that as well for me. Please

Comment: Could you please have a look at this, if you get time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73946620/error-in-data-frame-definition-while-multiple-ts-stat-forecasting-in-python