# Error in Data frame definition while Multiple TS Stat Forecasting in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, forecasting

I was trying to replicate this code for stat forecasting in python,
I came across an odd error ***"name 'forecasts' is not defined"*** which is quite strange as I was able to replicate the code without any errors before.

The difference here from this to the reference code (which is given in the link below and the code which I was successfully able to implement), I am not using a training set and extracting the last 6 months for evaluation and instead I am using the entire training data for creating a stat forecast.

Eg: If my time series data was till Sept-22, I wanted to give the entire data till Sept-22 as the training set for my stat model and previous the training data had time series till March-22 and the rest 6 months was test. But now there are Errors which I am not able to understand why as the logic is same?

Attached is the simplified data frame used for the calculation:

```
{'Key': {0: 65162552161356, 1: 65162552635756, 2: 65162552843456, 3: 65162552842856, 4: 65162552736856}, '2021-04-01': {0: 31, 1: 0, 2: 281, 3: 207, 4: 55}, '2021-05-01': {0: 25, 1: 0, 2: 72, 3: 104, 4: 6}, '2021-06-01': {0: 16, 1: 0, 2: 108, 3: 32, 4: 14}, '2021-07-01': {0: 8, 1: 0, 2: 107, 3: 78, 4: 10}, '2021-08-01': {0: 21, 1: 0, 2: 80, 3: 40, 4: 9}, '2021-09-01': {0: 24, 1: 0, 2: 40, 3: 73, 4: 3}, '2021-10-01': {0: 13, 1: 0, 2: 36, 3: 79, 4: 11}, '2021-11-01': {0: 59, 1: 0, 2: 65, 3: 139, 4: 14}, '2021-12-01': {0: 51, 1: 0, 2: 41, 3: 87, 4: 10}, '2022-01-01': {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 43, 3: 47, 4: 6}, '2022-02-01': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 63, 4: 3}, '2022-03-01': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 16, 3: 76, 4: 18}, '2022-04-01': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 37, 3: 32, 4: 8}, '2022-05-01': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 106, 3: 96, 4: 40}, '2022-06-01': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 101, 3: 75, 4: 16}, '2022-07-01': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 60, 3: 46, 4: 14}, '2022-08-01': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 73, 3: 91, 4: 13}, '2022-09-01': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 19, 3: 17, 4: 2}}
```

Here is the link for reference : https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-forecasting-with-statistical-models-f08dcd1d24d1

```
import random
from itertools import product
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsforecast import StatsForecast
from nixtlats.data.datasets.m4 import M4, M4Info
from statsforecast.models import (
    adida, 
    croston_classic, 
    croston_sba, 
    croston_optimized,
    historic_average,
    imapa,
    naive,
    random_walk_with_drift, 
    seasonal_exponential_smoothing,
    seasonal_naive, 
    seasonal_window_average,
    ses, 
    tsb,
    window_average
)
df = pd.read_excel ('C:/X/X/X/2.1 Demand_Data_Used.xlsx')
df['Key'] = df['Key'].astype(str)
df = pd.melt(df,id_vars='Key',value_vars=list(df.columns[1:]),var_name ='ds')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Key', 'unique_id')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('value', 'y')
df["ds"] = pd.to_datetime(df["ds"],format='%Y-%m-%d')
df=df[["ds","unique_id","y"]]

df['unique_id'] = df['unique_id'].astype('object')
df = df.set_index('unique_id')
df.reset_index()

seasonality = 30 #Monthly data

models = [
    adida,
    croston_classic,
    croston_sba,
    croston_optimized,
    historic_average,
    imapa,
    naive,
    random_walk_with_drift,
    (seasonal_exponential_smoothing, seasonality, 0.2),
    (seasonal_naive, seasonality),
    (seasonal_window_average, seasonality, 2 * seasonality),
    (ses, 0.1),
    (tsb, 0.3, 0.2),
    (window_average, 2 * seasonality)
    ]

fcst = StatsForecast(df=df, models=models, freq='MS', n_jobs=cpu_count())
%time forecasts = fcst.forecast(6)
forecasts.reset_index()

forecasts = forecasts.reset_index().merge(df_test, how='left', on=['unique_id', 'ds'])
models = forecasts.drop(columns=['unique_id', 'ds', 'y']).columns.to_list()
```

Attached is the error image:

[image]

Can anyone let me know what is it that I am doing wrong? It would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because of the Croston family. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast/issues/258) to solve the problem. In the meantime, skipping those models works.

```py
models = [
    adida,
    #croston_classic,
    #croston_sba,
    #croston_optimized,
    historic_average,
    imapa,
    naive,
    random_walk_with_drift,
    (seasonal_exponential_smoothing, seasonality, 0.2),
    (seasonal_naive, seasonality),
    (seasonal_window_average, seasonality, 2 * seasonality),
    (ses, 0.1),
    (tsb, 0.3, 0.2),
    (window_average, 2 * seasonality)
    ]
fcst = StatsForecast(df=df, models=models, freq='MS', n_jobs=cpu_count())
fcst.forecast(6)
```

Update:

The newest version of `StatsForecast` fixes the issue. You can use it using,

```
from statsforecast.models import CrostonClassic, CrostonSBA, CrostonOptimized

models = [
    CrostonClassic(),
    CrostonSBA(),
    CrostonOptimized()
]

fcst = StatsForecast(df=df, models=models, freq='MS', n_jobs=cpu_count())
fcst.forecast(6)
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification of the same. I really wanted to know the results of Croston Models. Is there any other way to implement Croston Models.
Also, the same line of code works fine with other data set which I initially used for testing, that's the surprising part. Also is there any way, I could know when the issue would be fixed?

Comment: Were you guys able to resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes, the newest version of `StatsForecast` fixes the issue related to the Croston family.

Comment: I tried to reinstall the library using `Pip install StatsForecast` and restarted the kernel but I run into the same error as shown above. Doesn't seem like its fixed. Did I get something wrong here?

Comment: You could use `pip install -U statsforecast` to update the newest version. Here's a colab example showing that now it works as expected: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vwIImCoKzGvePbgFKidauV8sXimAvO48#scrollTo=ICAhj-pNO6_A